# SHA1 hash differ between openssl and hashlib/pycrypto

Tags: python, openssl, pycrypto, hashlib

Why does the hash from using openssl differ from the ones I get in python?

```
$ echo "Lorem ipsum" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hex
(stdin)= d0c05753484098c61e86f402a2875e68992b5ca3
$ python
>>> from hashlib import sha1
>>> sha("Lorem ipsum").hexdigest()
'94912be8b3fb47d4161ea50e5948c6296af6ca05'
>>> from Crypto.Hash import SHA
>>> SHA.new("Lorem ipsum").hexdigest()
'94912be8b3fb47d4161ea50e5948c6296af6ca05'
```

Are the strings not equivalent? am I missing something obvious?

**Edit:** Thanks for spotting it. Was piping a saved message from a file which also suffer from the same annoying newline issue.

```
$ cat message | openssl dgst -sha1 -hex
'keep whacking your head mate, it wont be the same'
$ echo -n $(cat message) | openssl dgst -sha1 -hex
'ok, you got me, for now'
```

Comment: Common, yes, obvious, not really.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're missing the endline that `echo` will append by default:

```
echo "Lorem ipsum" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hex
(stdin)= d0c05753484098c61e86f402a2875e68992b5ca3
```

With the `-n` parameter, it will echo *only* the string that you gave it, for expected result:

```
echo -n "Lorem ipsum" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hex
(stdin)= 94912be8b3fb47d4161ea50e5948c6296af6ca05
```

Answer (score 6):

echo is putting a newline at the end of the string

```
>>> sha("Lorem ipsum\n").hexdigest()
'd0c05753484098c61e86f402a2875e68992b5ca3'
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo` adds a newline character to the string. The option -n suppresses the tailing newline:

```
> echo -n "Lorem ipsum" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hex
94912be8b3fb47d4161ea50e5948c6296af6ca05
```